# Quicktime playing unfinished HLS event playlist can't seek

Tags: http-live-streaming, quicktime, m3u8

I have an HLS playlist of type EVENT. It has the `#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT` tag. The playlist is not finished. It does not have an `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag.

When I play the playlist in Quicktime, it doesn't allow me to seek around. Since this is an event playlist, all the previous segments are available. Quicktime should have everything it needs to seek back.

I have tried this on OS X 10.6 and Maverick and the problem occurs. I have also tried this on an old iPad running iOS 5. On iOS 5 the problem doesn't occur.

Here is the playlist itself:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0,PRECISE=NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,
live_robocop_hd-rate_01_6512.ts
#EXTINF:10,
live_robocop_hd-rate_01_6513.ts
#EXTINF:10,
live_robocop_hd-rate_01_6514.ts
#EXTINF:10,
live_robocop_hd-rate_01_6515.ts
# ... more segments here ...
```

Comment: Did you find any more info about this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Nope. I didn't manage to work around this.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing, and have used the popular flash-based players that support HLS. I can't get any of them to work as expected on an event stream. By expected, I mean as described by Apple here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-EVENT_PLAYLIST

Comment: Flowplayer with the flashls plugin (an entirely non-Quicktime player stack) does play event playlists similar to yours reasonably well.